# Understanding Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am trying to understand the difference between [spring boot](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.1.RELEASE) and [spring boot web](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.1.RELEASE). From this [boot tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) the pom contains spring boot as the parent and spring boot web as a dependency like so:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

What are the uses for the 2 different versions? Do you always use them together? This spring boot [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-enabling.html) tells me if the program is production ready to use:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But if that's the case then why isn't there one for web like so:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are lots of these different 'starter' poms for spring boot. Each one of them tells maven to bring in the dependencies needed for that particular functionality. So `spring-boot-starter-web` brings in all the stuff needed for MVC and autoconfigures it with sensible defaults. The real trick to spring boot is it when it autoconfigures things it uses a whole of `@ConditionalOnClass` or other such annotations that look at what dependencies are on the classpath and provides configuration for those dependencies. What this means is when you have that spring boot actuator starter, when it's doing its autoconfiguration it will look at what other spring boot start poms you have in your `pom.xml` and it will configure different endpoints for the actuator so you can see the various metrics the actuator provides for that particular module.

Comment: What would be an example of a particular metric that the actuator provides?

Comment: /info
/health
/beans
/env
/dump
/metrics
/trace
/autoconfigurationreport
/shutdown.

Those are a few. /beans will tell you what beans the spring context knows about. /env will tell you a lot about what environment the spring boot application is running in. Like OS etc. But those are only the endpoints configured if just actuator is loaded. Like I said before, when you have other starter poms in your pom.xml spring boot will set up endpoints for additional metrics about those modules. It's really cool.

Comment: http://image.slidesharecdn.com/spring-141226061542-conversion-gate01/95/springboot-up-your-development-22-638.jpg?cb=1419574611

There's an example of all the data that /metrics endpoint will give you. As you can see it's pretty comprehensive and very very very cool to be able to get access to all this stuff by just including the actuator start pom in your pom.xml

Comment: Furthermore, if you don't want other people being able to access this stuff you can lock it down with Spring Security. And seeing as it is just a RESTful api returning JSON data you can build a nice graphical front end for it if you want, secure it Spring Security and make a really cool administration dashboard out of it.

Comment: In fact [here](https://blog.codecentric.de/wp-content/blogs.dir/2/files/2014/09/screenshot-metrics1.png) is a really cool example of somone who has done just that.

Answer (score 3):

Spring Boot is a framework, `spring-boot-starter-web` is one of the packages that comes with it, a `jar` file.

Just like `JDK` is a library, and `util` is one of the packages included in the JDK.

Comment: oh i see, so then I wouldn't even need to specify the web dependency in the pom? I could just have the `spring-boot-starter-parent` specified as the parent and that would be all i need?

Comment: @Richard The parent `pom.xml` file does not include the dependency for `spring-boot-starter-web`, you have to include it yourself as a maven dependency. Just hold ctrl or command key and click the parent pom file, you will see what is in there

Comment: but in the spring boot tutorial i linked above if you scroll down to where the pom.xml is you can see that they have the `spring-boot-starter-parent` and `spring-boot-starter-web` defined

Comment: thats because the tutorial wants to  `spring-boot-starter-web` as a dependency when first created the project.

Comment: ok so that answers my question i guess. The `spring-boot-starter-web` is not necessary to define in the pom.xml. You can just put `spring-boot-starter-parent` and that'll be enough. Is that right?

Comment: If you want to build a web application, you need `spring-boot-starter-web`, otherwise you can totally left it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100700/discussion-between-richard-and-jason-z).

Answer (score 3):

From: https://docs.spring.io

Spring Boot provides a number of “Starters” that auto-configures your application adds jars to your classpath. The spring-boot-starter-parent is a core starter that provides useful maven defaults. It also provides a dependency-management section so that if you import additional starters then you can omit version tags for “blessed” dependencies. Therefore you should only need to specify the Spring Boot version number on this dependency

Starters are a set of convenient dependency descriptors that you can include in your application considering each starter covers a specific area.The starters contain a lot of the dependencies that you need to get a project up and running quickly and with a consistent, supported set of managed transitive dependencies.For example, if you want to get started using Spring and JPA for database access, just include the "spring-boot-starter-data-jpa" dependency in your project, and you are good to go.
Spring Boot 
spring-boot-starter-web is starter for building web, including RESTful, applications using Spring MVC. It uses Tomcat as the default embedded container

Spring Boot has different groups of starters like

1-**Spring Boot application starters**:  spring-boot-starter-web , spring-boot-starter-jdbc , spring-boot-starter-jpa etc

2-**Spring Boot production starters** : spring-boot-starter-actuator  which provides production ready features to help you monitor and manage your application

3-**Spring Boot technical starters**: spring-boot-starter-jetty ,  spring-boot-starter-tomcat  these starters can be used to exclude or swap specific technical facets

Answer (score 3):

1.spring-boot-starter-parent deals with the auto start of main method and run methods so on.. 
2.and spring-boot-starter-web deals with the spring MVC things like controller, autowired so on.. Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot is a very cool tool of Spring Source. In many conference the team talck about of Spring Boot as one of the three DSR(Domain Specific Run-Time) of Pivotal.... Spring Boot, Spring XD and Grails(now Pivotal didn't support Groovy & Grails).

That said compare Spring boot stand alone and Spring boot web enviroment may be a cool conversation. First of all Spring boot give you many production ready istruments such as actuator(avaiable whit sprin boot in web enviroment), spring remote shall and so on. The main difference is the same of had a spring stand-alone context or a Spring web context. Of course some of the potentiality that yon could have are avaiable in a web context, Actuator is an example. but the main difference is in what kind of application you need, web or stand-alone.